# Get raw bytes from QR Code with zxing lib (or convert from BitMatrix)

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I need to get `byte[] array` from a QR Code encoded into a `BitMatrix`. Here's my code:

```
// imports
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.ChecksumException;
import com.google.zxing.FormatException;
import com.google.zxing.Writer;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.google.zxing.common.DecoderResult;
import com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter;
import com.google.zxing.datamatrix.decoder.Decoder;
```

The function to generate QR Code:

```
public byte[] createQRCode() {
    String qrCodeData = "Hello world";
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    BitMatrix matrix = null;
    Writer writer = new QRCodeWriter();

    try {
        matrix = writer.encode(new String(qrCodeData.getBytes(charset), charset), BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, qrCodeheight, qrCodewidth);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return;
    }
    catch (WriterException e) {
        return;
    }

    DecoderResult decoderResult = null;
    try {
        decoderResult = new Decoder().decode(matrix);
    } catch (ChecksumException e) {
        return;
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        // Always this exception is throwed
    }

    byte[] cmd = decoderResult.getRawBytes();`
    return cmd;
}
```

Always the execution stop on `FormatException`, even the parameter on `Decode().decode()` requested is `BitMatrix`.

Someone can tell me what's wrong or show me other way to get the QR Code `byte` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using a library to decode Bitmap:
https://github.com/imrankst1221/Thermal-Printer-in-Android

Function to encode String into QR Code Bitmap:

```
public Bitmap encodeToQrCode(String text, int width, int height){
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix matrix = null;
    try {
        matrix = writer.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width, height);
    } catch (WriterException ex) {
        //
    }
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, matrix.get(x,y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Then I decode bitmap to bytes using Utils from the found library:

```
try {
    Bitmap bmp = encodeToQrCode("Hello world", 200, 200);
    if (bmp != null ) {
        byte[] command = Utils.decodeBitmap(bmp);
        BluetoothPrintDriver.BT_Write(command);
    } else {
        Log.e("Print Photo error", "file not found");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("PrintTools", "file not found");
}
```